# Putting an image in Author footnote

Tags: graphics, titles

I want to protect my email address from automatic web crawlers. 
Is there a way to put an image of an email address instead of typed one in the author field and use it for `\maketitle`?

I want the following format, so that the email (and affiliation) is in the footnote:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\title{Titulo}
\author{Socrates\thanks{Email picture file here: }}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

\end{document}
```

[image: Desired Format]

The following throws an error:

```
\author{Socrates\thanks{Email: \includegraphics{email.png}}
\maketitle
```

Thanks to the pointer by *egreg*, `\protect` addresses the issue:

```
\author{Socrates\thanks{Email: \protect \includegraphics{email.png}}
\maketitle
```

Thanks in advance.

UPD: Edited to add the screenshot.

UPD2: Added solution I was looking for.

Comment: Did you try `\protect\includegraphics`?

Comment: egreg, right on, thank you!
I will update my MWE in a moment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The command `\includegraphics` is fragile, so you have to `\protect` it in footnotes.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\title{Titulo}
\author{Socrates\thanks{Email:
  \protect\includegraphics[
    width=4cm, % just for the example
    height=\ht\strutbox]{example-image}}%
}

\textheight=8cm % just for the example

\begin{document}

\maketitle


\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I understand you want to insert a picture in the author section. I hope I'm right.

if so, you can use:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
%opening
\title{Titulo}
\author{A. Robles R.\\
\includegraphics[scale=0.5]{mail}
}
\begin{document}
\maketitle

\end{document}
```

the output is:

[image]

Luck!, I hope will be useful

Comment: Thank you, your advice is great if one wants an email right after the author's name. I am trying to put the email (and affiliation, etc.) in the footnote. Will update my original post in a minute.